# Set a Symfony2 config default value based on another config setting

Tags: php, symfony, configuration-files

With Symfony2, I know how to use a Configuration.php file to set up what options are available for a bundle through config.yml. However, I'm not sure how to set one option to default to the value of another one (or if this is easily doable).

What I'm looking for is to have a Configuration something like this:

```
->scalarNode('option_one')
    ->defaultValue('peanuts')
    ->cannotBeEmpty()
->end()
->scalarNode('option_two')
    ->defaultValue('%option_one%')
->end()
```

So that with:

```
# config.yml
my_bundle:
    set_one:
        option_one: foo
        option_two: bar
    set_two:
        option_one: baz
    set_three: ~
```

For `set_one` we would then have `option_two` set to `bar`.

For `set_two`, `option_two` would be set to `baz` (via the default setting which matches it to `option_one`).

And for `set_three`, both `option_one` and `option_two` would be set to the default of `peanuts`.

Maybe I'm looking in the wrong place, though... perhaps there is somewhere else in the configuration process that 'missing' values could be caught and set to defaults based on their sibling values (or the wider configuration)?

Comment: As is usually the way, I think I just figured this out... after taking time to write up the question. In `MyBundleExtension::load()` it looks like you can manipulate the config after calling `$this->processConfiguration()`. I hope this is a sensible thing to do!

Answer (score 2):

The docs for [`validate()`](https://github.com/symfony/config/blob/c2c944db9441554c0718ce6169183521c035c3c0/Definition/Builder/NodeDefinition.php#L277) say (emphasis mine):

> The expression receives the value of the node and must return it. **It can modify it.**

So you can leverage this feature to actually set the defaults based on other values as you desire.

```php
->scalarNode('option_one')
    ->defaultValue('peanuts')
    ->cannotBeEmpty()
->end()
->scalarNode('option_two')
    ->defaultNull()
->end()
->validate()
  ->always(function(array $config) {
    if (!$config['option_two']) {
      $config['option_two'] = $config['option_one'];
    }
    return $config;
  })
->end()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two possibilities to do it:

- Dynamically modify the configuration in the extension as you pointed out in your comment.
- Play with normalization as explained [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/definition.html#normalization) with a closure.